# Saving data to SQLite.Net on a Background Service

Tags: xamarin, service, xamarin.android, sqlite.net

I'm working on a Xamarin Android application. At the moment I'm pulling down data from a Web Service to get objects of Foo. To make this app an Offline app, I am also saving each item into the database after each iteration of parsing the Foo data.

This does make the app slow so I was thinking of saving the items on the Background Service and queue each Foo item to be saved.

Can you Queue items to be saved and pass them to the Background Service and once done allow notify the UI?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

Comment: Thanks for that. I know the information about it but I'm worried my service would with the above example wouldn't work. Was hoping to get some input on best standards. I guess I'd just have to try.

Comment: @SmiffyKmc, I know this is an old question, however did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @markpirvine I never managed to actually get a solution for it. I just save using the SQLite.Net functions.